# How to access Google Chrome Extensions (Session Buddy) via Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to access [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=en-US) using Python.
In my case "access" means to get all currently opened URLs from Chrome.

Session Buddy allows you to save all opened URLs into a .csv file.
To do so you need to "setup" a few things (simplified: press buttons) and then all URLs are downloaded to Chromes /Downloads directory.

I would like to fully automate this process though. This means python needs to access Session Buddy, initiate the download and then save the file to the directory you want it to.

I can't use requests or something though since an extension won't work using an URL. This is what the extension calls: chrome-extension://edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko/main.html

In general, I don't necessarily want to use Session Buddy to get all the URLs, it just seems to be the easiest way..
So, in summary, I just want to ask: How can I automatically use Python to fetch all currently opened URLs in my Chrome Browser (using Session Buddy)?

I'm thankful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium webdriver and load .crx(extension) file to automate

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('path_to_extension')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path,chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: changed my code from java selenium to python's chromedriver